# React not Rendering correctly after update of Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a simplified version of Todo App [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-tesla-rhrrf).

But I have a problem regarding the delete function. I have this delete snippet:

```
 const Delete = () => {
    console.log(`deleted: ${index}`);
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(newTodos);
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };
```

**Problem:**

Try to add atleast 2 Todos.

Whenever I delete for example the `Index 0` the `last Index` will be deleted instead.

And after checking the `todos`, it is outputting the correct value but not in the interface.

Comment: What value do you get for the `console.log(newTodos)`

Comment: The correct value after I delete

Comment: .splice(0,1) will remove the first element from the array and update the old array as well. I don't understand the problem. Isn't this you are looking for ?

Comment: @informer I'm pretty sure the console.log(`deleted: ${index}`) is logging the supposed index to be deleted

Comment: if the index is -1, then element will be deleted from backwards. Check your index value.

Comment: I have a feeling the problem will be from the `setTodos` instead of this block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list component you use the index for the key

```
return <Item key={i} name={todo} index={i} />;
```

use the item instead

```
return <Item key={todo} name={todo} index={i} />;
```

it will fix the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-margulis-14qxo

Comment: It's already working. Can you elaborate why is it not working before? I thought index is a safe value to pass as a key

Comment: It is some kind of sideeffect. You could not use index as a key if the array element changing. With index is should work but with less efficient way.

Comment: The problem here could be, that you store the name in Item as a local state. You should not do that. It would be better to store your data in a single place. In the toto array and change its value there also.

Answer (score 3):

@jt25 I think your function is right but you are not passing a unique key in the parent view of your for loop item.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where your index comes from, that should be as param of the Delete function, looks some global variable, and be sure it is correct in the Delete closure.

Use an id, do not remove elements by the index, and assign as key of the React element the same todo it. Then on delete pass as argument the clicked todo's id.

In addition, do not mutate your state directly and use the callback for setting the state based on prev value:

```
const Delete = id => {
    setTodos(prevTodos => prevTodos.filter(t => t.id !== id)); 
  };
```